# Pass connections with https using pauseOnConnect

Tags: node.js

I am using the `pauseOnConnect` option on `net.createServer()` to allow me to pass connections to workers I created using cluster.

```
server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect : true }, function(connection){
    console.log('passing connection to worker...');
    // received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate worker
    var workerIndex = getWorkerIndex(connection.remoteAddress, numberOfProcesses);
    var worker = workers[workerIndex];
    worker.send("sticky-session:connection", connection);
}).listen(portNumber, function(){
    logger.info("Server started on port " + portNumber);
});
```

Is there a way for me to use `pauseOnConnect` with https, either by using the https module or converting a `net` server to use https?

Answer (score 3):

I have created an example based on [Elad's solution](https://github.com/elad/node-cluster-socket.io)

Here is a full example of how to use both (http and https) servers with node.js cluster

```js
var express = require('express'),
    cluster = require('cluster'),
    http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),
    sio = require('socket.io'),
    fs = require('fs');

var httpPort = 3000,
    httpsPort = 4000,
    num_processes = require('os').cpus().length,
    httpsOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('pkey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
    };

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // This stores our workers. We need to keep them to be able to reference
    // them based on source IP address. It's also useful for auto-restart,
    // for example.
    var workers = [];

    // Helper function for spawning worker at index 'i'.
    var spawn = function(i) {
        workers[i] = cluster.fork();

        // Optional: Restart worker on exit
        workers[i].on('exit', function(code, signal) {
            console.log('respawning worker', i);
            spawn(i);
        });
    };

    // Spawn workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        spawn(i);
    }

    // Helper function for getting a worker index based on IP address.
    // This is a hot path so it should be really fast. The way it works
    // is by converting the IP address to a number by removing non numeric
    // characters, then compressing it to the number of slots we have.
    //
    // Compared against "real" hashing (from the sticky-session code) and
    // "real" IP number conversion, this function is on par in terms of
    // worker index distribution only much faster.
    var worker_index = function(ip, len) {
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 0, _len = ip.length; i < _len; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(ip[i])) {
                s += ip[i];
            }
        }

        return Number(s) % len;
    };

    // Create the outside facing server listening on our http port.
    var httpServer = http.createServer();
    httpServer.on('connection', function(connection) {
        //pauseOnConnect
        connection.pause();

        // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
        // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
        // it the connection.
        if(connection.remoteAddress) {
            var worker = workers[_workerIndex(connection.remoteAddress, numProcesses)];
            worker.send(eventMessage, connection);
        }
    });
    httpServer.listen(httpPort, function() {
        console.log('http-Server up and running at %s port', httpPort);
    });

    // Create the outside facing server listening on our https port.
    var httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions);
    httpsServer.on('connection', function(connection) {
        //pauseOnConnect
        connection.pause();

        // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
        // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
        // it the connection.
        if(connection.remoteAddress) {
            var worker = workers[worker_index(connection.remoteAddress, num_processes)];
            worker.send('sticky-session:https-connection', connection);
        }
    });
    httpsServer.listen(httpsPort, function() {
        console.log('https-Server up and running at %s port', httpsPort);
    });
} else {
    // Note we don't use a port here because the master listens on it for us.
    var app = new express();
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send("Hello World!");
    });

    // Here you might use middleware, attach routes, etc.

    // Don't expose our internal server to the outside.
    var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(0, 'localhost'),
        httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(0, 'localhost'),
        io = sio(httpServer);
    io.attach(httpsServer);

    // Here you might use Socket.IO middleware for authorization etc.

    // Listen to messages sent from the master. Ignore everything else.
    process.on('message', function(message, connection) {
        if ( (message !== 'sticky-session:connection' && message !== 'sticky-session:https-connection') || !connection ) {
            return;
        }

        switch(message) {
            case "sticky-session:connection":
                // Emulate a connection event on the http server by emitting the
                // event with the connection the master sent us.
                httpServer.emit('connection', connection);
                break;
            case "sticky-session:https-connection":
                // Emulate a connection event on the https server by emitting the
                // event with the connection the master sent us.
                httpsServer.emit('connection', connection);
                break;
        }

        connection.resume();
    });
}
```

Comment: Working fine for me. Exact solution i am looking for.